# while he was the head of the organization

Tags: punctuation, clauses, commas

**a. The betrayals while he was the head of the organization were few.**

Does this mean

1. The betrayals that took place while he was the head of the organization were few.
   ?

============================

**b. The betrayals, while he was the head of the organization, were few.**

Can't this mean both:

2. While he was the head of the organization, the betrayals were few.

and

3. The betrayals, which took place while he was the head of the organization, were few.
   ?

In (3) all the betrayals we are talking about took place while he was the head of the organisation.

My feeling is that (a) is totally unambiguous, but that (b) is ambiguous.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Placing commas around the time-frame phrase introduced by **while** does not alter the meaning in any way. There is no ambiguity.

**while** indicates that two events occurred concurrently or that an event took place during a specified time frame.

Concurrency:

> He washed windows while she mopped the floor.

Taking place during a time frame:

> Her dreams  while she was on that medication were strange and vivid.

Your example is of the latter type.

**The betrayals while he was the head of the organization were few.**

The word **while** introduces a phrase that defines the time-frame:

... while he as head of the organization

The thing or things which took place during the time frame: "The betrayals".

And now that we have established a time-frame, we can also make a statement about them in other respects:

The betrayals {while he was head of the organization} *were few*.

You can rearrange the sentence and not alter the meaning, and you can choose to use commas or not, and the meaning remains the same.

> While he was head of the organization[,] betrayals were few.
>
> Betrayals were few[,] while he was head of the organization.
>
> There were few betrayals while he was head of the organization.
>
> While he was head of the organization there were few betrayals.

The noun **betrayals** refers to *incidents of betrayal* and so of course we understand that they took place or happened. There is no need to add "which took place" or "which happened".

Comment: Thank you so much. I see your point, but isn't it possible to read (b) in another fashion? Couldn't it be construed as equivalent to: 1. 'The betrayals, which took place while he was the head of the organization, were few'? In that case, ALL the betrayals took place when he was the head of the organization. 'When he was the head of the organization, the betrayals were few.' implies that there were betrayals at other times...